# Converting sympy matrix to two-form (sympy.diffgeom)

Tags: python, sympy

Is there any way to convert a symmetric SymPy matrix to two-form ?

When I try to use

```
sym.diffgeom.metric_to_Christoffel_1st(expr)
```

for the following matrix

```
Matrix([[a**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta))**2, 0, 0], 
        [0, a**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta))**2, 0], 
        [0, 0, a**2*sinh(eta)**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta))**2]])
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: The input expression is not a two-form.
```

The matrix expression is the metric for the transformation between Cartesian and Toroidal coordinates. I get the same error when I try to use the metric on the other `sympy.diffgeom.metric_to_*` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your metric matrix is stored in variable *m*, you can do:

```
diff_forms = your_coord_system.base_oneforms()

metric_diff_form = sum([TensorProduct(di, dj)*m[i, j] for i, di in enumerate(diff_forms) for j, dj in enumerate(diff_forms)])
```

Beware that for one-forms, *TensorProduct(dx, dy) = -TensorProduct(dy, dx)*, this means that if your matrix is not diagonal, element *m[i, j]* will be summed to element *m[i, j]* for *i != j*.

If you have a symmetric matrix, and you wish to add the off-diagonal elements only once, then add a *1/2* term for *i != j*.

Comment: The storage of tensor-like data structures is an open question in SymPy. There are various different implementations (matrices for 2 dim tensors, oneforms, numpy arrays, lists of lists, and others).

Comment: That did the trick. But I was not expecting a trivial result like : ((((0, 0), (0, 0)), ((0, 0), (0, 0))), (((0, 0), (0, 0)), ((0, 0), (0, 0)))) for the Riemann tensor. Which is not correct.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. I fixed that so that the manifold is three dimensional. Here is the new output :                                                           ((((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))),
 (((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))),
 (((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))))                                                                             which is still incorrect

Comment: I will add a new question for my specific problem.